# 20.10: Unable to setup either EFI or legacy boot

Tags: boot, partitioning, grub2, uefi, boot-repair

System specs (after everything described below): https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/87pyy86mZq/

I'm trying to install Kubuntu 20.10 from LiveUSB to replace an existing Ubuntu installation. The drive (sda) has an MBR table with two existing ext4 partitions, sda1 (/) and sda2 (/home). I choose to format sda1 and keep sda2, with the same mount points. I also resize sda1 down by a few GB and use the free space to create a swap partition (sda5).

The installer appears to run fine, but eventually terminates with `unable to install GRUB on dev/sda1. executing grub-install /dev/sda failed. This is a fatal error.` When I try to boot the drive, I enter grub rescue mode:

```
error: file '/boot/grub/i386-pc/normal.mod' not found.
Entering rescue mode...
grub rescue>
```

Running the LiveUSB, I see that `/boot/grub` is missing all but a few files, so I can't do much in grub rescue. I attempt to run boot-repair instead: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

The repair tells me: `The boot of your PC is in EFI mode, but no EFI partition was detected. You may want to retry after creating a EFI partition(FAT32, 100MB~250MB, start of the disk,boot flag).`

Presumably, this is why the installer failed in the first place. Realizing I don't know enough about different boot modes, I quit the boot-repair and start reading up. Afterwards, my understanding is that I should either

1. boot the LiveUSB in legacy mode, then repair/reinstall, if I want legacy boot (which I probably had before), or
2. create an EFI System Partition (ESP), then repair/reinstall, if I want EFI boot, in which case I would boot from the ESP.

I attempt option 1 first. On machine startup I enter Asus UEFI Bios Utility, which displays the USB drive twice in the boot menu: one of them is prefixed with "UEFI:" and the other one should be legacy mode. However, selecting the legacy mode apparently fails to boot the USB and falls back to default boot order. There is no error message, just a black screen for a while and then I end up in grub rescue. I try fiddling with advanced settings but to no avail.

I attempt option 2 next. I run the Kubuntu installer again, taking 512 MB from swap to make an EFI System Partition (sda3). This time the installer finishes without errors. I reboot, but the EFI partition apparently fails to boot and I still end up in grub rescue. I try running boot-repair from LiveUSB again. I no longer get the message from before and the repair seems to run without problems. Log: https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/tsqjr9SX9f/

At the end the repair says `Please do not forget to make your UEFI firmware boot on the Ubuntu 20.10 entry (sda3/EFI/ubuntu/shimx64.efi file) !`. Looking at the log, it seems this is already done (am I wrong?). "UEFI: ubuntu" shows up as the first boot option in the UEFI Utility but still fails to boot. I just end up in whatever's next in the boot order, either the LiveUSB or sda (which launches grub rescue). To be certain, I remove the USB and disable CSM so that "UEFI: ubuntu" is the only remaining option but it still won't boot. Instead, the UEFI Utility launches automatically on startup.

Any ideas on how to proceed? Is there any way to tell why the boot fails? I've found conflicting information on whether an MBR table is compatible with EFI boot and if I should use GPT instead. Switching to GPT would completely format the drive though, right? Is there any way to setup legacy boot even if the LiveUSB is booted in EFI mode? I usually install Ubuntu first on my machines and then KDE on top of it, but I don't think that would make much difference here?

Possibly relevant: My previous installation always (seemingly) booted directly into Ubuntu, without a bootloader menu. I'm not sure how it worked, but I don't recall having any trouble with installation back then. I do see grub in the backup of my old root.

Comment: There is no reason to use MBR unless installing Windows in old BIOS boot mode. I have used gpt since 2010 on BIOS only system. You can convert but it changes UUIDs so at minimum grub reinstall & edit of fstab required. Often easier to just reinstall & restore from your backup. Converting from MBR to gpt:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1454252 My z97 required multiple UEFI settings, should be similar. Asus z97 screenshots:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2258575&page=2

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The gptfdisk tool gave me warnings about the number of entries in my current table and suggested a possibility of data loss, so I was a bit hesitant to try it, not knowing if GPT would solve the boot problem. I did eventually manage to get legacy boot to work, but if it ever turns out I have to switch to EFI boot after all, I'll be sure to recheck your links.

Comment: Did you or installer create a bios_grub partition, 1MB unformatted with bios_grub flag?  You need that for grub to correctly install for BIOS boot on gpt. If UEFI boot you must have an ESP - efi system partition as FAT32 300 to 500MB.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually managed to get legacy boot to work as follows. I'd read in multiple places that as long as the LiveUSB itself was booted in legacy mode, it would also install Linux with legacy boot. Using Rufus (https://rufus.ie/) I was able to create a LiveUSB that successfully boots in legacy mode on my machine. I verified the boot mode with inxi, which now said `BIOS` instead of `UEFI`, and with efibootmngr, which said `EFI variables are not supported on this system.`

The installer itself also seemed to acknowledge the legacy mode at first. However, after I'd erased the now needless ESP and confirmed my new partition table, the installer said: `No EFI System Partition was found. This system will likely not be able to boot successfully, and the installation process may fail. Please go back and add an EFI System Partition, or continue at your own risk.`

This seemed strange since if I'm installing with legacy boot, I shouldn't need an ESP anymore? Moreover, I did not get this warning during my very first attempt despite the fact that back then I also had no ESP ***and*** the LiveUSB was booted in EFI mode. I decided to continue anyway, and the installer again failed to install grub, same as the first time.

This time, however, the boot-repair tool correctly recognized the legacy mode. Following the instructions (pasting a bunch of lines in a shell), the tool successfully installed grub and my machine now boots into Kubuntu just fine.

My only concern is that the installer terminated when it failed to install grub. Was installing grub the final step, or was there perhaps something more to be done afterwards? Everything seems to work fine so far, at least.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this when installing Kubuntu on my legacy bios machine.  I always install to the root partition and left /home alone.  The installation needed to (without saying so) make a /boot/efi partition but there was no room due to my other partitions.  The installation failed as mentioned above.

Not knowing what to do, I did an install and let it repartition the entire drive.  I then split the main partition into / and /home and restored my /home from backup.  Not ideal, but a simple way to recover that others may find useful.

The big questions is: why is /boot/efi needed on a old legacty Bios machine starting with Kubuntu 20.10?